# Variable scoping and event handler

Tags: javascript, scope, event-handling, dom-events

Please see the jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/LsNCa/2/

```
function MyFunc() {

    for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) { // i= 0, 1
        var myDiv = $('<div>');
        
        myDiv.click(function(e) {
            alert(i);    // both the two divs alert "2", not 0 and 1 as I expected
        });
        $('body').append(myDiv);
    }
}

var myFunc = new MyFunc();
```

I want the divs to alert "0" and "1" respectively when I click them, but both of them alert "2".

When I click the divs and the event is triggered, how and where do the handler find the value of the variable `i`?

I'm aware that adding a closure achieves my goal. But why?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript infamous Loop problem?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451009/javascript-infamous-loop-problem)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
    function MyFunc() {

    for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) { // i= 0, 1
        (function(j) {
            var myDiv = $('<div>');

            myDiv.click(function(e) {
                alert(j);
            });
            $('body').append(myDiv);
        })(i);
    }
}

var myFunc = new MyFunc();
```

The code above is how you get it work correctly. Without an closure, you always the the last value of i. What we do is to post i into the closure and let the runtime "remember" the value of that very moment.

Comment: Is this the standard way of doing it? If the loop body is fairly long, do we still wrap it inside an anonymous function?

Comment: This is the usual idiom. But you could use Zenwolf's style if you prefer for longer functions.

Comment: As I can see people usually write it this way. try not to do this in a big loop. I mean like for(var i = 0; i < 1000; i++).

Answer (score 2):

You need a closure because all your event handler functions are referencing the same variable `i`. The `for` loop updates this, and when the loop is done the variable contains `2`. Then when someone clicks on one of the DIVs, it accesses that variable.

To solve this, each event handler needs to be a closure with its own variable `i` that contains a snapshot of the value at the time the closure was created.

Comment: You said you know the correct way to write it, you just wanted an explanation of why that's needed. I'm not sure what code I can write that will illustrate the answer -- your code does that just fine.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you read [this article](http://bonsaiden.github.io/JavaScript-Garden/#function.scopes)

> JavaScript hoists declarations. This means that both var statements
>   and function declarations will be moved to the top of their enclosing
>   scope.

As @Barmar said in his answer above, the variable `i` is being referenced by both the event handlers.

You should avoid declaring functions inside loops. Below there is some code that does what you need.

I assume that you're using jQuery.

```
function MyFunc() {

    for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) { // i= 0, 1
        var myDiv = $('<div>');

        $('body').append(myDiv);
    }
    $('div').on('click', function() {
        alert($(this).index());
    });
}

var myFunc = new MyFunc();
```

Answer (score 0):

The "alert()" call happens after the for-loop completed, which means that the value of "i" will be the last value for anything after that. In order to capture individual values of "i", you must create a closure for each value by creating a new function:

```
function MyFunc() {

    function alertFn(val) {
        return function () {
            alert(val);
        };
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        var myDiv = $('<div>');
        myDiv.click(alertFn(i));
        $('body').append(myDiv);
    }
}

var myFunc = new MyFunc();
```

The closure captures the value of "i" at the time it was passed into the function, allowing alert() to show the value you expect.